# Why does more features in a random forest decrease accuracy dramatically?

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

I am using sklearn's random forests module to predict values based on 50 different dimensions. When I increase the number of dimensions to 150, the accuracy of the model decreases dramatically. I would expect more data to only make the model more accurate, but more features tend to make the model less accurate.

I suspect that splitting might only be done across one dimension which means that features which are actually more important get less attention when building trees. Could this be the reason?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the additional features you have added might not have good predictive power and as random forest takes random subset of features to build individual trees, the original 50 features might have got missed out. To test this hypothesis, you can plot variable importance using sklearn.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is **overfitting** the data.

From Wikipedia:

An overfitted model is a statistical model that contains more parameters than can be justified by the data.

https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-412c8556aacf7e25b86bba63e9e67ac6-c

There are plenty of illustrations of overfitting, but for instance, this 2d plot represents the different functions that would have been learned for a binary classification task. Because the function on the right has too many parameters, it learns wrongs data patterns that **don't generalize** properly.

Comment: I think the user is talking about training accuracy going down and not validation accuracy